# Is there any other way to start React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm, jsx

Whenever I clone any React app into my system or copy the code of one React app into another React app, it does not start and shows the following message;

> gym-app@0.1.0 start    > react-scripts start    & was unexpected at this time.

also attached in the screenshot. I have already updated nodejs, npm, and vs code. however, I don't get any error in my office system.

I tried updating Nodejs and VS Code and also double-checked the code. It didn't work.